# Blog Post Exceprt in REST API call

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

I want to display latest posts widget on my website, while blog is on different domain and I use latest WordPress. I call WP REST API to get posts:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
```

And I want to limit post excerpt, but it doesn't work. I tried different plugins, it works for wordpress itself but not for API, I tried filters in my theme functions.php:

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 100;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 100 );
```

Nothing works. How can I do that?

Comment: is your priority high enough - on the codex they use 999?

Comment: I tried different priorities, it was 999 and same no result